# Removing only empty line break, preserving spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove extra line breaks, so that texts are one after another, while preserving white spaces (used as indents)

I have the following:

```
report_text = report_text.split("\n").map($.trim).filter(function(line) { return line != "" }).join("\n");
```

which will return with lines of text one after another (which is correct), but will also remove my indents (two or more white spaces) because of the `$.trim`

I don't know of any other way to keep my "indents" and just **only** remove empty line breaks. Is there a way I can have each line of line string one after another, but preserve all my white spaces.

Comment: may be also some like `(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n')`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply `report_text.replace(/\n+/g, "\n")`?

Comment: You rock my socks! Simple-er, elegant-er, couldn't be happy-er!

Comment: This works perfectly but leaving last empty line break as it is. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this version:

```
report_text.replace(/(\n)+/g, "$1")
```

For more information read this article: ['RegExp Capturing Groups'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).